# Facebook login button center align in android application

Tags: android, facebook, android-layout, authentication

I am using LinerLayout and one Facebook login button image.
I want to keep margin from top 50dp and keep image as center align. 
Depends on screen images in not coming in center when i am using following code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
     tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/loginwithfb" 
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
       />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Better you use Relative layout and android:layout_centerInParent="true" for child

Comment: How about setting the **gravity**??